# http authentication using apiary / api blueprint

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary

Just dipping my toes into Apiary and API Blueprint, and having some problems with passing in some basic http authentication.

On an initial call, the API creates a token for any given user that needs to be used with any subsequent call. My problem is how to mark-up that authentication so it works with the Apiary production request.

The command-line curl (that works) is (in obfuscated code) this...

```
curl --user name@somewhere.com:tokenGoesHere http://test.server.uri/API/getUserInfo
```

So, how do I convert that curl command into the equivalent API Blueprint format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way, at the moment, to specify authentication/authorisation in APIBlueprint.

It's in the [roadmap](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/11), but unfortunately we can't give you any precise ETA on that.

You might want to read our [help page on the argument](https://help.apiary.io/api_101/authentication/) as well.